# Count number of questions, answers and comments on a tag

Tags: support, api

Is it possible (and allowed) to get the number of all questions, answers, and comments for a specific Tag and publish them on a website?

Comment: This info is readily available from the data dump and SEDE.  Content is licensed as CC-by-SA so you can do anything you want with it.  Just post a link to your SEDE query.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for that fast answer. The query basicly works, besides it returns 0 for quering the amount of questions. Would you like to take a quick look at it? Thank you very much! http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/433357/ironpython-questions (In the query i select only IronPython questions).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's an issue with the join you are using between `Posts` and `PostTags`, use: `p.Id = t.PostId`:

Try this one: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/433365#resultSets

```
SELECT 
    Count(*) AS QuestionCount
FROM 
    Posts p
JOIN PostTags t on p.Id = t.PostId
WHERE 
    t.TagId = 1589
    AND p.PostTypeId = 1 -- Questions
```

**Edit:**

As stated in the comments by [Conrad Frix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/119477/conrad-frix):

> ...the tag table has a count that represents the question count e.g.
>
> `SELECT Count From Tags Where TagName = 'sql'`

Comment: Do you know, if it is possible to embed those result in an external webpage?

Comment: i guess create an iframe would be one (hacky) way

Comment: @jimtollan, Unfortunately, that would not work, as SE prevents embedding their sites (incl Data.SE) in an iframe, plus there's a captcha, so no embedding possible. The only way would be just to put the information wherever it's needed manually, and update manually, and periodically.

Comment: gotcha - makes sense

Comment: @JonasCz [Manually isn't the only way](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316538/119477)

Comment: @Conrad, true, you can do it with with the API - however if you want to do it on the web, it may be more trouble than it's worth, due to JavaScript same origin policy, thus requiring you to set up a server-side "proxy" of some kind. Good point though, upvoted.

Comment: @JonasCz The [usage section](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) here indicates that Cross origin calls are accounted for

Comment: @Tanner minor quibble on the sql.. the tag table has a count that represents the question count e.g. `SELECT Count From Tags Where TagName = 'sql'`

Comment: @ConradFrix good point, I didn't look at it in too much detail, just noticed that the join was wrong in the query he posted.

Answer (score 5):

The following [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1620392?tag=ironpython) returns, for posts in a specific tag, the counts for questions, answers, comments, views and bookmarked. You can select the tag you're interested in as a parameter

```sql
select sum( case when posttypeid = 1 then 1 else null end)  [Questions]
     , sum( case when posttypeid = 2 then 1 else null end)  [Answers]
     , sum( case when posttypeid  in (1,2) then 1 else null end)  [Total]
     , sum( case when posttypeid = 1 then commentcount else 0 end)  [Q-cmts]
     , sum( case when posttypeid = 2 then commentcount else 0 end)  [A-cmts]
     , sum( case when posttypeid  in (1,2) then commentcount else 0 end)  [Tot-cmts]
     , sum( case when posttypeid = 1 then cast(Favoritecount as bigint) else null end)  [Tot-Bookmarked]
     , sum( case when posttypeid = 1 then cast(Viewcount as bigint) else null end)  [Tot-Views]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname = ##tag:string?ironpython##
```

When run today this is your result:

[image: Questions: 2557; Answers: 3339; Total: 5896; Q-cmts: 3604; A-cmts: 3424; Tot-cmts: 7028; Tot-Bookmarked: 1971; Tot-Views: 5831997]

If you want to automate this result you would need to script that, for example by using a technique mentioned in [How to download the CSV result of the same Data Explorer query agains different Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137790/how-to-download-the-csv-result-of-the-same-data-explorer-query-agains-different)

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [/tags/{tags}/info](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name#order=desc&sort=popular&tags=sql&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) StackExchange API and then get the count out of the JSON result

For example passing SQL in for the tag for stackoverflow site gives this result

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "has_synonyms": true,
      "is_moderator_only": false,
      "is_required": false,
      "count": 314791,
      "name": "sql"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9989
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first two things can be answered without data.SE. Just search for `[tagname] is:question` and `[tagname] is:answer` and check the result count.